# GSON : Parsing JSON when keys are a part of response

Tags: json, gson, android

Here's the response I am trying to parse.

```
{"table":"PypersonResponsibleCrewMembersWklyView","numberOfRemainingRecords":0,"rowDefinition":{"attrNames":["EmpOraseq","{PEmpNo","PEmpName","Code","Name","EmpNo","EmpTrdCode","EmpTrdName","EmpFirstName","EmpLastName","NhHrsTot","OtHrsTot","DotHrsTot","NhHrs1","OtHrs1","DotHrs1","NhHrs2","OtHrs2","DotHrs2","NhHrs3","OtHrs3","DotHrs3","NhHrs4","OtHrs4","DotHrs4","NhHrs5","OtHrs5","DotHrs5","NhHrs6","OtHrs6","DotHrs6","NhHrs7","OtHrs7","DotHrs7"]},"rows":[{"attrValues":[211448,"1016","Mr. Demo","REL","aman","1004","PRES","President","Gord","Rawlins",0.5,0.5,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"attrValues":[211448,"1016","Mr. Demo","REL","aman","ESS001","PROE","Project Engineer","Nadal","Rafael",0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"attrValues":[211448,"1016","Mr. Demo","REL","aman","CL1001","SS01","System Specialist","Ronald","Bromell",0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]}
```

In this response 'attrNames' contains the keys and 'attrValues' contains the values. Is it possible to parse this using GSON?

Comment: Yes, make a custom deserializer for `Row` objects (each element in the `rows` list). https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics

Comment: @jspcal, In this case, the keys can be variable. The number of keys might increase or decrease in the future.